# Android GoogleApiClient: Can't connect

Tags: android, api, connection, client

I'm trying to implement the new `GoogleApiClient` into my android application, but the `GoogleApiClient` can't connect. I use `connect()` method, but the `isConnecting()` method returns always true and `isConnected()` is never true.

my code

**Init**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

**Connect**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if( mGoogleApiClient != NULL )
        mGoogleApiClient.connect()
}
```

**Open leaderboard**

```
private void openAchievements() {
  if( !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ) // always false
      return;

  startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
}
```

**Implements:**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "Connected!");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "connection failed");
}
```

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Meta-data:**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: where are you calling `openAchievements()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google 'Play Games' application and service don't work from last update. So i have to wait with testing my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you're building your Api Client you're adding connection callbacks and in your case it's the Activity itself implementing these callbacks.

And one of the methods that your activity should implement is [`onConnected()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected(android.os.Bundle)) which is called when the connection successfully established. So you need to call `openAchievements()` from this method. And then you can remove unnecessary check `!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()`